# Anyone know what this error I get when trying to use Entity Framework PoweTools CTP1 to generate the code first is

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Just tried to cheat my way through it and use PowerTools CTP1 to generate the POCO entities and all navigational properties from an existing *.mdf database file but get the following error, hopefully won't need to type up all entities by hand a long with navigational properties etc.:

```
    System.ArgumentException: The modelEntityContainerName parameter 'C:\USERS\ADMIN\DOCUMENTS\VISUALSTUDIO2010\PROJECTS\MYCART\MYCARTWEBUI\APP_DATA\MYDBMDFContext' contains characters that are not valid.
   at System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityModelSchemaGenerator..ctor(EntityContainer storeEntityContainer, String namespaceName, String modelEntityContainerName)
   at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.DbContextPackage.ReverseEngineerCodeFirst(Project project)
```

Comment: FYI, you don't have to use code first to use the new dbContext API, and have poco's.  You generally only need Code first if you are defining your database from scratch.  In most other cases, you get the same poco generation and dbcontext api by doing a Database First approach, then using the DbContext generator t4 tempates to generate your DbContext class and pocos.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [Rowasn Miller's answer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d/view/Discussions/3):

> The reverse engineer doesn't work directly with mdf files at this stage, you will need to attach it to a SQL Server instance. Once you have reverse engineered you can detach it and update the connection string in your App/Web.config to work with the MDF.